# How to call ng-disabled with a function from web service response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

The ng-disabled has a function that takes the response from api and two parameters. But it never gets called after the response.

```
    function PermissionController(permissionResource) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.message = 'Permission';
    vm.permissions;

    permissionResource.query(function(data) {
        vm.permissions = data;            
    });

    vm.isPermissionMissing = function (r, a) {
                for(var i = 0; i < vm.permissions.length; i++) {
                    if(vm.permissions[i].Resource == r && vm.permissions[i].Action == a)
                        return -1;
                }

                return 1;
            };


}
module.controller("PermissionController", PermissionController);
```

Then my view has a button to show/hide with ng-disabled.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="isPermissionMissing('account', 'search')">Search</button>
```

Then a table with ng-repeat

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>resource</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="permission in vm.permissions">
            <td>{{ permission.Resource }}</td>
            <td>{{ permission.Action }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is by the time the page loads with the api response, it does not call the function in ng-disabled.

I tried the promise then with no luck.

```
        permissionResource.query(function(data) {
        vm.permissions = data;            
    }).$promise
        .then(function (result) {
            vm.isPermissionMissing = function (r, a) {
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if(result[i].Resource == r && result[i].Action == a)
                        return -1;
                }

                return 1;
            };
        });
```

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="vm.isPermissionMissing('account', 'search')">Search</button>

Answer (score 0):

The angular documentation shows ngInit being used with ngDisabled. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

In your instance I would move the function call to ng-init. Then in the function you need to create a scope variable to set true/false. Let me know if that works for you.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-init="isPermissionMissing('account', 'search')" ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}">Search</button>

vm.isPermissionMissing = function (r, a) {
            for(var i = 0; i < vm.permissions.length; i++) {
                if(vm.permissions[i].Resource == r && vm.permissions[i].Action == a)
                    vm.isDisabled = false;
            }

            vm.isDisabled = true;
        };enter code here
```